# Wizard101 Dworgyn backstory

Tags: wizard101

When we first meet Dworgyn in the fallen Death School, he says that he hasn't seen any students since Malastaire left and he is surprised to learn the the school has fallen to Nightside.  Merle Ambrose is surprised to learn that the Death School still exists.

Quest: The Sixth School

The school fell when Malastaire left: "When Malistaire Drake left Wizard City, he sunk the school into Nightside over his rage at his wife's death."  (http://www.wizard101central.com/wiki/Location:Nightside)

This seems to imply that Dworgyn was an assistant head, already at the school, when Malastaire left and Dworgyn did not know of the school's fall.

Yet when we meet Dworgyn in the BOXES event it is before his hire at Ravenwood and after the departure of Malastaire.  Dworgyn remembers Malastaire, but was not present at his departure.  He is being hired as a replacement.

Quest: Carnival of Monsters

So I am confused, when Dworgyn was hired, hadn't the death school already fallen?  How did he not know about its fall?

EDIT: I just did the "Meet the Professors" tour of Wysteria.  When talking to Edna Fulgin, she says "I've heard of problems with Professor Malastaire, back at Ravenwood.  Maybe his ASSISTANT Dworgyn will be better."

So if Dworgyn was his assistant, doesn't that imply Dworgyn was hired before Malastaire left, overlapped with him, and was NOT a replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dworgyn was hired as a replacement for Malistair, but that was before Malistare took down the death school. After Malistair left, Ambrose hired Dworgyn right away, but I think Malistair didn't immediately take it down. He came back after he quit then took it down.

Quest: The Savior (Level 75)

EDIT: Dworgyn was an assistant at first hired to aid Malistair. He later defected due to unknown reasons. After Malistair left, Ambrose called on Dworgyn to take over Malistairs place.

Comment: Thanks - my highest is currently 63, so I have not had that quest yet.

Comment: But see my EDIT above.